# Batch file that calls another batch fails to copy files

Tags: batch-file, call, xcopy

I have a series of batch files I use when setting up computers.  I want to be lazy and instead of running them all individually I want to call them from a single batch file.  I have that set up but its not working completely.  There is a batch file I `CALL` that uses `XCOPY` to move a bunch of shortcuts and icons but it wont copy them when called, only when directly ran.

I've also tried using `START`but it doesn't run any of the batch files then.

Main Batch, \Post Install\Run.bat

```
Call "Batch\Shortcuts.bat"
```

Shortcuts.bat, \Post Install\Batch\Shortcuts.bat

```
@echo off
@echo Copying Icons And Shortcuts
@echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "Shortcuts\Kronos.ico" "C:\Alle-Temp\"
@echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "Shortcuts\Workday.ico" "C:\Alle-Temp\"
@echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "Shortcuts\ADMS (New Windchill).url" "C:\Shortcuts\"
@echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "Shortcuts\ADMS Drawing Lookup.url" "C:\Shortcuts\"
@echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "Shortcuts\AMMS Web.url" "C:\Shortcuts\"
@echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "Shortcuts\As-400.lnk" "C:\Shortcuts\"
@echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "Shortcuts\WorkDay @ Work.lnk" "C:\Shortcuts\"
@echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "Shortcuts\Kronos @ Work.url" "C:\Shortcuts\"
@echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "Shortcuts\MapNetworkDrives - G & Q Drives Only.bat" "C:\Shortcuts\"
@echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "Shortcuts\McAfee x64.bat" "C:\Users\EsAdmin\Desktop\"
@echo ................................................................................
pause
```

Comment: What is the minimum batch file in order to reproduce the problem? E.g. I believe that all the `echo`s are not needed.

Comment: Shortcuts.bat executes (you see the echo output) but the xcopy commands don't work?  Have you tried specifying a full, absolute path for the icon and shortcut files that you are copying?

Comment: I think it is not seeing the relative path correctly. At the top of your run.bat put a `echo %cd%`.  Do the same in your shortcuts.bat file.

Comment: Looking at your example the two batch files appear to be in different directories and the shortcuts folder is in another sub-folder.  But when you call shortcuts.bat it is inheriting the environment from Run.bat and the current working directory for run.bat is C:\Post Install\ but the shortcuts directory is in C:\Post Install\Batch\Shortcuts.  So to correct this use the PUSHD and POPD commands in your shortcuts.bat file. `PUSHD %~dp0` at the top and `POPD` at the end.

Comment: If you want to see what is actually happening, remove or comment out the `@echo off` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your solution is:

Be sure to run this batch file in the same location as all the icons and shortcuts.

```
@echo off
echo Copying Icons And Shortcuts
echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "Kronos.ico" "C:\Alle-Temp\"
echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "Workday.ico" "C:\Alle-Temp\"
echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "ADMS (New Windchill).url" "C:\Shortcuts\"
echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "ADMS Drawing Lookup.url" "C:\Shortcuts\"
echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "AMMS Web.url" "C:\Shortcuts\"
echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "As-400.lnk" "C:\Shortcuts\"
echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "WorkDay @ Work.lnk" "C:\Shortcuts\"
echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "Kronos @ Work.url" "C:\Shortcuts\"
echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "MapNetworkDrives - G & Q Drives Only.bat" "C:\Shortcuts\"
echo ................................................................................
xcopy /y /r /v "McAfee x64.bat" "C:\Users\EsAdmin\Desktop\"
echo ................................................................................
pause
```